# How do I put my output print the keywords* in alphabetical order (abc) instead of backwards(zyx)? This is a binary search tree implementation in java

Tags: java

class bst{

```
Node root; // a Node object

public class Node{
  
    String keyword;
    Record record;
    int size; //number of keywords 
    Node l; //left node
    Node r; //right node

    private Node(String k){
  // TODO Instantialize a new Node with keyword k.
        keyword = k;
    }

    private void update(Record r){
        //TODO Adds the Record r to the linked list of records. You do not have to check if the record is already in the list.
        
        //HINT: Add the Record r to the front of your linked list.
        if(this.record==null) {
            this.record = r; 
        }
        else {
            r.next = this.record;// the new record will be placed to the next node
            this.record = r;
        }
    }

    public boolean contains(Node curr) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
} // end of node class

// back to bst class

public bst(){
    this.root = null; //the bst root is not connected to anything
}
  
public void insert(String keyword, FileData fd){
    Record recordToAdd = new Record(fd.id, fd.author, fd.title, null);
    //TODO Write a recursive insertion that adds recordToAdd to the list of records for the node associated
 
    //with keyword. If there is no node, this code should add the node.
  
  
    
    if(root==null) { // root is from node class
        root = new Node(keyword);
        root.update(recordToAdd);
    }
    else {// if there is a node, start inserting, call the insert help function
        insertHelp(keyword, recordToAdd, root);
    }

}
private Node insertHelp(String keyword, Record recordToAdd, Node nObj) {
    if(nObj.keyword.equals(keyword)) {
          nObj.update(recordToAdd);
          return nObj;
        
    }
    // inserting node to the left
    else if(nObj.keyword.compareTo(keyword)<0) { 
        if(nObj.l==null) { // if it is empty, create a left node
            nObj.l = new Node(keyword);
            nObj.l.update(recordToAdd);
            return nObj.l;
        }
        else { // otherwise keep on inserting to the left
            return insertHelp(keyword,recordToAdd, nObj.l);
        }
    
    }
    //inserting node to the right 
    else if(nObj.keyword.compareTo(keyword)>0) { 
        if(nObj.r==null) { // if it is empty, create a right node
            nObj.r = new Node(keyword);
            nObj.r.update(recordToAdd);
            return nObj.r;
        }
        else { // otherwise keep on inserting to the right
            return insertHelp(keyword,recordToAdd, nObj.r);
        }
    
}   
return null;// do nothing
}

public boolean contains(String keyword){
    //TODO Write a recursive function which returns true if a particular keyword exists in the bst
  
    //if the root does not exist
    if(this.root==null) {
        return false;
    }
    
    //if the root exists, then it starts to look for other nodes
    else { 
        Node help =  containsHelp(root,keyword);
    if(help==null) { // if the node isn't found, return false
        return false;
    }
    else { // if found, return true 
        return true;
    }
    }
}
private Node containsHelp( Node nObj,String keyword) {
    
    if(nObj.keyword.contentEquals(keyword)) {
        return nObj;
    }
    // if the left side of bst exists
    else if(nObj.keyword.compareTo(keyword)<0) { 
        return containsHelp( nObj.l,keyword);
    }
    //if the right side of bst exists
    else if(nObj.keyword.compareTo(keyword)>0) { 
        return containsHelp( nObj.r,keyword);
    }
    return null; // do nothing
}

public Record get_records(String keyword){
    //TODO Returns the first record for a particular keyword. This record will link to other records
    //If the keyword is not in the bst, it should return null.
   
    if(root==null) {
        return null;
    }
    else {
        return containsHelp(root,keyword).record;
    }
        
}

public void delete(String keyword){
    //TODO Write a recursive function which removes the Node with keyword from the binary search tree.
    //You may not use lazy deletion and if the keyword is not in the bst, the function should do nothing.

root = deleteHelp(keyword,root);//node root
}
public Node deleteHelp(String keyword, Node nRoot) {
    //pointer to store parent node of current node
    Node parent = null;
    //start with root node
    Node curr = nRoot;
    //search keyword in BST and set its parent pointer
     while(curr != null && curr.keyword.compareTo(keyword)!= 0 ){
       //update parent node as current node
         parent = curr;
         //if given key is less than the current node, go to left subtree
          if(keyword.compareTo(curr.keyword)< 0){
              curr = parent.l;
          }//else go to the right subtree
          else{
              curr = parent.r;
          }
         
          
      } //end of search
    
     //if keyword isn't found in the tree
     if(curr ==null) {
      return nRoot;
     }
     //case 1: if the node does not have any children, delete
     // as known as leaf node
     if(curr.l==null&&curr.r==null) {
         if(curr!=nRoot) {
    //if node to be deleted is not a root node, then set
   //its parent left/right child to null
             
             if(parent.l==curr) {
                 parent.l=null;
             }
             else {
                
                 parent.r=null;
             }
        }
        
    //if tree has only one node, delete it and set root to null  
         else {
             nRoot=null;
         }
     }
     //case 2: node to be deleted has 2 children
     else if(curr.l!=null && curr.r!=null) {
         // find its in-order successor node
         Node successor=minKey(curr.r);
         deleteHelp(keyword,successor); //delete the successor node recursively
         curr = successor;  //copy current node into the successor.
      }
    //case 3: node to be deleted has only one child
     else {
         //find child node
         Node child=(curr.l!=null)?curr.l:curr.r;
    // if node to be deleted is not a root node. then set its parent
   //to its child
         if(curr!=nRoot) {
             if(curr==parent.l) {
                 parent.l=child;
             }
             else {
                 parent.r=child;
             }
         }
         else {
             nRoot = child;
            // nRoot = null;
         }
         
 
     }
        //if node to be deleted is root node, then set the root to child
        
     return nRoot;
}
    

// help function to find min value node in subtree rooted at curr 
public Node minKey(Node curr) {
    while(curr.l!=null) {
        curr=curr.l;
    }
    return curr;
    
}
public void print(){
    print(root);
}

private void print(Node t){
    if (t!=null){
        print(t.l);
        System.out.println("***************************");
        System.out.println(t.keyword);
        Record r = t.record;
        while(r != null){
            System.out.printf("\t%s\n",r.title);
            r = r.next;
        }
        print(t.r);
    } 
}
```

}
//here is my output:
Wesley Chu*
Knowledge-Based Image Retrieval with Spatial and Temporal Constraints
weighting*
Dan Aha
triangle-inequality*
Andy Berman
Andy Berman
John Barros
time-related
Joseph Han
temporal
Wesley Chu
spatial
Maria Ester
Wesley Chu
similarity
Andy Berman
John Barros
Ricardo Baeza-Yates
search
James Bach
relational
Chris Brunk
Joseph Han
region-based
Chuck Carson
recognition
Mauro Costa
Yi Li
query-trees
Ricardo Baeza-Yates
query-by-example
Paul Kelly
queries
Dave Angluin
pruning
Andy Berman
pose
Mauro Costa
neural-networks
Wayne Bunt
Yosama Mustafa
multimedia
Chris Faloutsos
medical
Wesley Chu
Paul Kelly
John Anderson
matching
Mauro Costa
Ricardo Baeza-Yates
lines
Yi Li
learning
Jaime Carbonell
Wayne Bunt
Wayne Bunt
Chris Brunk
Tom Huang
Dave Angluin
Dan Aha
Dan Aha
Dan Aha
Yosama Mustafa
Joan Catlett
knowledge
Joseph Han
Wesley Chu
instance-based
Dan Aha
instance-based
Dan Aha
information-retrieval
Jaime Carbonell
indexing
Mauro Costa
image-stack
Alfonso Cardenas
image-retrieval
Tom Huang
Wesley Chu
Alfonso Cardenas
Chuck Carson
Andy Berman
Andy Berman
John Barros
James Bach
Paul Kelly
John Anderson
image-management
James Bach
image-display
Alfonso Cardenas
distance-measures
Andy Berman
database
Greg Hulten
Joseph Han
Joseph Han
Soha Guha
Chris Faloutsos
Maria Ester
Gary Cooper
Joan Catlett
Paul Bradley
Paul Kelly
John Anderson
data-mining
Greg Hulten
Joseph Han
Joseph Han
Gary Cooper
content-based
Tom Huang
Chris Faloutsos
John Anderson
concepts
Chris Brunk
Dave Angluin
Dan Aha
Dan Aha
clustering
Soha Guha
Maria Ester
Paul Bradley
Yi Li
classification-rules
Wayne Bunt
Wayne Bunt
causal-relationships
Gary Cooper
buildings
Yi Li
blobs
Chuck Carson
weighting
Dan Aha
triangle-inequality
Andy Berman
Andy Berman
John Barros
time-related
Joseph Han
temporal
Wesley Chu
spatial
Maria Ester
Wesley Chu
similarity
Andy Berman
John Barros
Ricardo Baeza-Yates
search
James Bach
relational
Chris Brunk
Joseph Han
region-based
Chuck Carson
recognition
Mauro Costa
Yi Li
query-trees
Ricardo Baeza-Yates
query-by-example
Paul Kelly
queries
Dave Angluin
pruning
Andy Berman
pose
Mauro Costa
neural-networks
Wayne Bunt
Yosama Mustafa
multimedia
Chris Faloutsos
medical
Wesley Chu
Paul Kelly
John Anderson
matching
Mauro Costa
Ricardo Baeza-Yates
lines
Yi Li
learning
Jaime Carbonell
Wayne Bunt
Wayne Bunt
Chris Brunk
Tom Huang
Dave Angluin
Dan Aha
Dan Aha
Dan Aha
Yosama Mustafa
Joan Catlett
knowledge
Joseph Han
Wesley Chu
instance-based
Dan Aha
instance-based
Dan Aha
information-retrieval
Jaime Carbonell
indexing
Mauro Costa
image-stack
Alfonso Cardenas
image-retrieval
Tom Huang
Wesley Chu
Alfonso Cardenas
Chuck Carson
Andy Berman
Andy Berman
John Barros
James Bach
Paul Kelly
John Anderson
image-management
James Bach
image-display
Alfonso Cardenas
distance-measures
Andy Berman
database
Greg Hulten
Joseph Han
Joseph Han
Soha Guha
Chris Faloutsos
Maria Ester
Gary Cooper
Joan Catlett
Paul Bradley
Paul Kelly
John Anderson
data-mining
Greg Hulten
Joseph Han
Joseph Han
Gary Cooper
content-based
Tom Huang
Chris Faloutsos
John Anderson
concepts
Chris Brunk
Dave Angluin
Dan Aha
Dan Aha
clustering
Soha Guha
Maria Ester
Paul Bradley
Yi Li
classification-rules
Wayne Bunt
Wayne Bunt
causal-relationships*
Gary Cooper
buildings*
Yi Li
blobs*
Chuck Carson

Comment: You don't appear to have a binary search tree. You have three linked lists for elements that are smaller, greater or equal to the root element.

Comment: it is a combination of bst and linked lists.

Comment: Oh I see, the layout confused me. Normally you'd keep Node-related methods in your Node class and such.

Comment: my professor wanted me to use the files he provided for us

Answer (score 0):

If you are storing the keywords in the Tree correctly then all you need to do is preform a reverse inorder traversal on the tree to get the keywords in sorted order.

So your print(Node t) method should look something like this if you want to print the whole tree.

```
private void print(Node t){
    // Recurse to the bottom left of tree.
    print(t.right);
    System.out.println(t.l);
    // Print records here...
    print(t.left);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are building your tree with *larger* nodes on the *left*.

Your traversal algorithm prints left to right, so therefore it shows largest values first.

The order is because of your snippet here, where the comparison is reversed from what's normal:

```
else if(nObj.keyword.compareTo(keyword)<0) { 
    if(nObj.l==null) { // if it is empty, create a left node
        nObj.l = new Node(keyword);
```

If the current node is "B" and the node to insert is "A", then it becomes:

```
if("B".compareTo("A") < 0)  // False
```

If you swap the order, i.e.:

```
keyword.compareTo(nObj.keyword) < 0
```

Then the left will be smaller, and your tree will print in the expected order.

Alternatively, you can just keep the tree the way it is, but recurse the right-hand side first when printing the tree.

Comment: I swapped the order, but it gave me a complication error

Comment: I did just now. Thanks!